# Openvpn: access remote ip in the same subnet as pushed vpn subnet

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

I don't have access to openvpn server-side configuration.

To summarize, the server is pushing to the client this directive:

'PUSH_REPLY,**route-gateway 10.81.234.5**,sndbuf 0,rcvbuf 0,ping 45,ping-restart 180,redirect-gateway def1,topology subnet,route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway,inactive 900 7680,dhcp-option DNS x.x.x.x,dhcp-option DNS x.x.x.x,dhcp-option DOMAIN XXXXXX,**ifconfig 10.81.234.13 255.255.255.0**'

Unfortunately i need to access the remote ip **10.81.231.12** (same subnet as pushed openvpn subnet..)
what can I do?

I already tried to override the ifconfig on the client and adding new routes..

Comment: What do you mean, "i need to access the remote ip 10.81.231.12"? Do you need your OpenVPN client to have that address itself, or to connect to another host or VPN client with that address? It looks like you should be able to see everything on that subnet, though it is not uncommon for VPNs to prevent clients from seeing each other. Regardless, if something *does* need to be changed you would have to have access to the VPN configuration to make that happen. You won't be able to do it from the client.

Comment: I cant reach that ip from the client side.. I think because the ifconfig directive is creating a subnet 10.81.231.0-255 , so the Ip 10.81.231.12 is bot routed into the vpn gateway..